# Are questions tagged with [bug] on Meta guaranteed to be reviewed by mods/devs?

Tags: support, meta

In other words, is [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) just a tag as the other tags are, having no special mod/dev monitoring/lifecycle?

Comment: I know that the [bug]+ [chat] ends up in a chat room for the chat devs according to balpha

Comment: That's where the bug tag and chat tag are on the same question (on all sites). Forgot `[chat]` gets parsed into "sitename chat"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no guarantee, but as Ben already mentioned in a comment the developers are monitoring certain tags. This is not only true for Meta.SO, but also for all the child metas.

Still, sometimes bug reports are overlooked. If you notice an old bug report that you think needs some more attention, you can edit it or put a bounty on it if you have meta rep to burn. You could also write the SE team a mail, or ping a moderator you know in chat. We mods can annoy the community team directly, and they can then annoy the devs until they fix some stuff.

Comment: `We mods can annoy the community team directly` And we do it every chance we get ;)

Comment: Linking the old bug in [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) might also be worthwhile.